# Creating 'connection string' in CRM SDK 4 programmatically

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm writing application, which connects to CRM using CRM SDK 4. In the first version, I've been using app.config file (section 'connectionStrings')

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="mycrm" connectionString="Authentication Type=Integrated; Server=http://ServerName/OrganizationName;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

and (in code):

```
DataContext ctx = new DataContext("mycrm");
```

and it works fine. But now, application should let user to choose authentification type, type server name, user id, password, etc. I've created connection string, but I don't know how to use it. DataContext and CrmConnection objects, AFAIK, has only constructors with connectionString name (from app.config file) as parameter. When I try to use my connectionString I get exception:

```
    System.ApplicationException was unhandled
```

Message="Unable to load the connection string name 'Authentication Type=Integrated; Server=http://ServerName/OrganizationName;'"
  Source="Microsoft.Xrm.Client"
  StackTrace:
      at Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmConnection.GetConnectionStringFrom(String connectionStringName)
      at Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmConnection..ctor(String connectionStringName, String connectionString)
      at Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmConnection..ctor(String connectionStringName)
      at ARP.EstateExtensions.PaymentsUploader.MainWindows..ctor(String connectionString) in C:\Users\mrobaszynski\Desktop\PU\PaymentsUploader\MainWindows.xaml.cs:line 38
      at ARP.EstateExtensions.PaymentsUploader.LoginWindow.bOK_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\mrobaszynski\Desktop\PU\PaymentsUploader\LoginWindow.xaml.cs:line 92
      at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
      at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
      at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
      at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
      at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
      at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
      at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
      at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
      at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
      at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
      at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
      at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
      at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
      at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
      at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
      at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
      at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
      at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
      at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
      at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
      at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
      at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
      at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
      at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
      at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
      at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.TranslateAndDispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
      at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
      at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
      at PaymentsUploader.App.Main() in C:\Users\mrobaszynski\Desktop\PU\PaymentsUploader\obj\Release\App.g.cs:line 0
      at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
      at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.NullReferenceException
      Message="Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
      Source="Microsoft.Xrm.Client"
      StackTrace:
            at Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmConnection.GetConnectionStringFrom(String connectionStringName)
      InnerException:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the other post is wrong - do NOT use reflection.  The proper way to do this would be to use CrmConnection.Parse(customConnectionString) to build a crm connection.  You can then construct the data context with that connection in the constructor.

var crm = new XrmDataContext(CrmConnection.Parse(customConnectionString));

Shan McArthur

www.shanmcarthur.net